# Accidentally lost Chrome "tabs from other devices". Please save me

Tags: google-chrome, mac

I've managed to lose my Chrome "tabs from other devices".

I'm running Google Chrome Version 89.0.4389.114 (Official Build) (x86_64).

MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3 on a MacBook Pro 2017.

Up until a couple of days ago, I was able to see on the 2017 the "tabs from other devices", including the tabs which were on a Macbook Pro 2015.

A couple of days ago, I wiped the 2015 completely.

Because I could see all the 2015 "tabs from other devices" on the 2017, it didn't occur to me that if I wiped the 2015, I would no longer be able to see on the 2017 the "tabs from other devices" from the 2015.

Now on the 2017, I can't see any "tabs from other devices", presumably because the Chrome server can no longer find the wiped 2015.

I've got a backup of the Chrome folder from a couple of weeks ago on the 2017, before I wiped the 2015.

Are the "tabs from other devices" saved only on the Chrome server, or were they also saved on the hard drive of the 2017 a couple of weeks ago?

In plain English, do you know of any way that I can retrieve my "tabs from other devices", either on the 2017's hard drive, or on the Chrome server?

I pray that you can give me a positive answer.

Thanks.

Best,

MichaelT

Answer (score 0):

Email addresses trash column, look for any saved emails or feedback from any sights you may desire & you should be able to find it there.